# Handling errors in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, exception

A few questions on handing errors-
I assume it's best to handle them in Application_OnError(){}?

Do you then prefer to write them error to the event log, write them to a custom file locally or email them?

If the latter, do you use any specialist libraries to pre-format the exception email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at ELMAH: http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Comment: Wow, the summary sounds fantastic.

Comment: Another vote for Elmah. I've used it in various projects in the past and it works well. The only limitation I haved found is that you have to create your own custom handler in order to have elmah log to the windows event log if that is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

For some applications we use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), for others we use the [EnterpriseLibrary Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309257.aspx). They both can write the errors to a log file in a predefined format. The Logging Application Block also supports sending the error by email. Well worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

If you take no action at all, ASP.NET Health Monitoring will log the errors for you. By default it will log to the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 1):

you should also handle "unhandled exceptions". see [here](http://blog.theobjectguy.com/2009/12/exceptional-gotchas.html) . YOu can read more about it in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx)